# Access 07 VBA Get Table by Path

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to reference (in VBA) a non-linked Access table by its full path?

For instance, say you're building a form that draws from a set of tables, but your user needs to add tables as time goes on; you might start with `tableA`, `tableB`, and `tableC`, but a year down the line `tableZ` might exist.

The goal then becomes finding a way to reference the newly-added tables without needing to add them as external data sources if possible; [how] can this be done? (My particular case involves using the tables as RowSource values, if that's significant.)

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
control1.RowSource = "X:\database\databaseName.accdb" & [???]
```

might work, but I really have no idea what would go in the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within an Access query, there are 2 ways to reference an unlinked table in a different Access database.

```sql
SELECT YourTable.some_field
FROM YourTable IN 'X:\database\databaseName.accdb';
```

or ...

```sql
SELECT YourTable.some_field
FROM [X:\database\databaseName.accdb].YourTable;
```

I think you can get what you want if you use a similar query as your `RowSource`. (`Control.RowSource = "SELECT ..."`)

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I was looking for-- could you edit your answer to clarify that the query literal ("SELECT ...") can be used as the RowSource directly? It took me a while to figure that out, so having it there might help others.

Comment: As a follow-up, is it necessary that the database being referenced is open when this call is made?

Comment: No.  Access will establish the connection it needs --- if you watch in Windows Explorer and refresh at just the right instant you might even see the  databaseName.lccdb lock file it creates when opening the connection.  On the other hand, if databaseName.accdb is already in use at the moment the query runs, it can't be open in exclusive mode or the query will fail.